# how to insert few columns data into a single row of other table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I want few columns of a table data into a single column of  other table with out using union all.

For example, if the original table is:

```
    acct   col1  col2  col3
      1      x      y     z
      2      a      b     c
```

I want a new table (with value as a column)

```
value
   x
   a
   y
   b
   z
   c
```

The order does not matter to me.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `SELECT col1 FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT col2 FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT col3` FROM table

Answer (score 4):

This process to convert columns into rows is known as UNPIVOT. Since you are using SQL Server you can perform this a few different ways.

You can use the UNPIVOT function:

```
select value
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (col1, col2, col3)
) un;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3074a/1).

Depending on your version of SQL Server (if 2008+) you can use CROSS APPLY with VALUES:

```
select value
from yourtable
cross apply
(
  values
    ('col1', col1),
    ('col2', col2),
    ('col3', col3)
) c(col, value);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3074a/2).  Both of these will convert the columns into rows without using UNION ALL, you can then insert this data into another table if needed.

Answer (score 2):

From sqlserver 2008 you can use UNPIVOT

```
-- test table
DECLARE @t TABLE(acct int, col1 char(1), col2 char(1), col3 char(1))  
insert @t values(1,'x','y','z')
insert @t values(2,'a','b','c')


-- query
SELECT value  
FROM @t as p  
UNPIVOT      
(value FOR Seq IN           
([col1], [col2], [col3]) ) AS unpvt
```

Result:

```
value
x
y
z
a
b
c
```

Comment: its working fine .what about performence to this qry? will it halt the  performence?